# Align and label in chemical equation

Tags: vertical-alignment, labels, mhchem

1. How to only label the second, third and sixth line with 1, 2, 3?
2. the arrow with catalyst in first line is a little bit longer than others. How can I extend others or let it shorter?
3. How to label the second and third line with A, and fourth, fifth and sixth with B?

[image]

```
\begin{align*}
    \ce{3H+ + 3BrO3^- + 5CH2(COOH)2 & ->[Ce3+] 3BrCH(COOH)2 + 4CO2 + 5H2O + 2HCOOH}\\
    \mathrm{A:} \ce{Br- + BrO3^- + 2H+ & -> HBrO2 + HBrO}\\
      \ce{Br- + HBrO2 + H+ & -> 2HBrO}\\
    \mathrm{B:}\ce{Br- + BrO3^- + 2H+ & -> HBrO2 + HBrO}\\
      \ce{BrO2. + Ce3+ H+ & -> HBrO2 + Ce4+}\\
      \ce{2HBrO2 &-> BrO3- + H+ +HBrO}
\end{align*}
```

Comment: How should lines with dual labels (both numbers and letters) be typeset? Should it be, say, `(3B)`, `(3,B)`, `(3)(B)`, or something else? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico Is it possible for one equations have 2 lables? A, B on the left and 1, 2, 3 on the right?

Comment: And what should happen with the `A:` and `B:` items currently on lines 2 and 4?

Comment: I add it manually, is it possible to use `\something{}` to get the same result with the A and B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first objective, change from an `align*` to an `align` environment and use `\notag` directives on lines 1, 4, and 5.

For the second, load the `mathtools` package and replace `->[Ce3+]` with `& ->[$\mathclap{\ce{Ce3+}}$]`.

For the third, simply use two extra implicit columns and insert `\textnormal{(A)}` and `\textnormal{(B)}` directives as needed.

And do replace `\mathrm{A:}` with `\textnormal{A}\colon`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,mhchem}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page size parameters appropriately
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
&&\ce{3H+ + 3BrO3^- + 5CH2(COOH)2 
  & ->[$\mathclap{\ce{Ce3+}}$] 
     3BrCH(COOH)2 + 4CO2 + 5H2O + 2HCOOH} \notag\\
\textnormal{(A)}&&
\textnormal{A}\colon \ce{Br- + BrO3^- + 2H+ 
  & -> HBrO2 + HBrO}\\
\textnormal{(A)}&&
\ce{Br- + HBrO2 + H+ 
  & -> 2HBrO}\\
\textnormal{(B)}&&
\textnormal{B}\colon \ce{Br- + BrO3^- + 2H+ 
  & -> HBrO2 + HBrO} \notag\\
\textnormal{(B)}&&
\ce{BrO2. + Ce3+ H+ 
  & -> HBrO2 + Ce4+} \notag\\
\textnormal{(B)}&&
\ce{2HBrO2 
  &-> BrO3- + H+ +HBrO}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With `flalign*`, `\phantom` and `\notag`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
  & & \ce{3H+ + 3BrO3^- + 5CH2(COOH)2 & ->[Ce3+] 3BrCH(COOH)2 + 4CO2 + 5H2O + 2HCOOH}\notag\\
  & (\mathrm A) & \mathrm{A}\colon \ce{Br- + BrO3^- + 2H+ & ->[\phantom{Ce3+}] HBrO2 + HBrO}}\label{eq-1}\\
  & (\mathrm A) & \ce{Br- + HBrO2 + H+ & ->[\phantom{Ce3+}] 2HBrO}\label{eq-2}\\
  & (\mathrm B) & \mathrm{B}\colon \ce{Br- + BrO3^- + 2H+ & ->[\phantom{Ce3+}] HBrO2 + HBrO}\notag\\
  & (\mathrm B) & \ce{BrO2. + Ce3+ H+ & ->[\phantom{Ce3+}] HBrO2 + Ce4+}\notag\\
  & (\mathrm B) & \ce{2HBrO2 &->[\phantom{Ce3+}] BrO3- + H+ +HBrO}*\label{eq-3}
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to refer the `\tag{1}`? `\ref{1 =}`doesn't work.

Comment: You didn't say you want a referable number. In this case, use `flalign`  (the unstarred version), and `\notag` with the lines you don't want to refer to. Of course the letters (A) and (B) at the beginning of lines are not referable.